# Sencha: remove dynamically created components using CSS class

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

In my sencha mobile web app I have dynamically created elements/containers in my view.

Each has a uniquie id but all same the same css class.

I am trying to find a way to remove them using the css class. The reason I need to use the css class and not the id is that the number created cannot be determined at runtime.

I have tried `Ext.select('.myContainer').remove();` but that give error "has no method 'remove' "

I also tried
`var main = Ext.getCmp('mainpage');

main.remove(main.down('.siteContainer'));`

but that did nothing at all.

I'm still new to Sencha. Any advice would be very much appreciated.

I was hoping for something similar to jquery's `$('.classname').remove()` which will work on multiple elements at the same time.

Comment: You're going about it the wrong way, the selectors are for components, not for css. You'll need to explain what you're doing.

Comment: @evan-trimboli I have added a number of components (x-type: container). I need to be able to remove them all without refering to the id/itemId

Comment: Based on what criteria are you removing them? Index?

Comment: I have a selectfield, which passes the value of the selected option to a function. I need the dynamically created containers to be removed from the view if the selected option = 'XXX'

Comment: There's still not really enough info, why don't you set up a test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using jquery to get the ID of each component with the same class, then used senchas destroy() on the acquired ID.

`$( $('.siteContainer') ).each(function( index ) {

var thiscont = $(this).attr('id');

    Ext.getCmp(thiscont).destroy();

});`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with [removeNode](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-removeNode) or with [destroy](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-destroy) ?

Comment: gracias. I used a combination of jquery and destroy()